# Clean way to close dropdown list when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a button that opens a dropdown list when clicking on.

I want to close this list when clicking outside the button. So I used a `HostListener` like this:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
toggleDropdown(element) {
    const clickOnDropdownButton = (): boolean => {
        const buttonChildsClasses = ['button is-primary tog-button', 'dropdown-label', 'tog-icon tog-icon-arrow-down', 'icon is-small'];
        return buttonChildsClasses.indexOf(element.className) !== -1;
    };
    if (this.dropDownActive) {
        this.dropDownActive = false;
    } else if (!this.dropDownActive && clickOnDropdownButton()) {
        this.dropDownActive = true;
    }
}
```

This works but the use of a possible childs array is not clean at all in my opinion.

Indeed, the problem with my button is that it is composed of several HTML elements, my button isn't just a `button` tag.

I thought of having a HTML element on top of those other elements using `position: absolute` but I'm not sure if it's cleaner.

Any thoughts on this problem ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you use Angular CDK to implement dropdown component, its really very nice！

you can see Example in my github  https://github.com/100cm/at-ui-angular/blob/master/src/app/components/dropdown/dropdown.component.ts

Comment: the way i solved this was to add a click handler on the parent element of the dropdown (containing the dropdown opener button and the options list) and calling event.stopPropagation() there

Comment: You can use a simple Jquery script and include that on the pages with dropdowns, nice thing is you can reuse this for all dropdowns all around your site. Maybe not the best option, but it is a simple option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //this is your dropdown list in html 
    <div #dropdown> </div>

    //this is your ts

    @Component({ 
       host: {'(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',}
      })


 @ViewChild('dropdown', {read: ElementRef}) dropdown: ElementRef;


    handleClick(event) {
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
            do {
                if (clickedComponent !== this.dropdown.nativeElement) {
                    it's call when we click outside the dropdown list
                }

            while (clickedComponent);
    }
```